# variable using ognl expression within id doesn't display value

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

Hi this seems to be a weird issue since the variable works when I print it out through s:text tag but when I put it in the id tag it doesn't work.

The id in div would literal print out %{param} but s:text would print out the value of the param variable. Am I missing something here? Any advice or suggestion be great!

```
<s:set var="param" value="%{parameters.param}"/>
<div id="%{param}">
    <s:text  name="%{param}"/>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe the problem is that you use tag `<s:text` from jsp, but div it is only html

Comment: Thank you! That completely went right under my nose!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this will work:

```
<div id="<s:property value='param'/>">
```

#### UPDATE

Below is the real solutions:

```java
<div id="<s:property value='%{param}'/>">
```

Comment: FYI this is what worked for me <div id="<s:property value='%{param}'/>">